# How to stop instagram app remembering / auto-filling in username at login screen, when not yet logged in

Tags: ios, login-screen, auto-complete, instagram

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Log out of instagram app
2. Close the app
3. click on it to open it and log back in
4. Log-in screen is displayed, with the user name filled in (not yet logged in (i.e. still logged out)) and password field beneath blank

How do you clear all Instagram app settings and what it remembers *after* you have logged out? So that it doesn't remember (i.e. forgets) your user name so that it doesn't pre-fill in this field at the login screen?

There are options to clear data in the Settings screen, but these are too blanket and coarse in that they clear everything - I only want to clear one thing.

Problem seen on Sep 2010 (4th generation) iPod touch 32Gb. IOS Version 6.1.5 (10B500)

Latest version of Instagram app, as of date 2014 05 18.

Comment: have you tried deleting and installing again ?

Comment: @WM what outcome would I expect from that? Would I have to do this every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to Instagram app → Profile → Settings → scroll down to Privacy & Security → Saved Login Info → Turn it off.

Comment: For those looking for this on the instagram.com desktop website, the setting does not seem available to turn off there.

Answer (score 2):

Tap on Instagram app>open app info >clear data 
this will remove your autofill username in Instagram account

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, log out of your Facebook account! This worked for me when nothing else did.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to remove all accounts it lets you choose which accounts to take away

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the log out all accounts button you should be able to choose which accounts it will remember. Log out and then you will only see the accounts you chose to keep.

Comment: If you downvote because it is wrong, please say so.  If it's not wrong, then it answers the question clearly.  An unexplained downvote on an apparently good answer is 100% useless.