# How to completely clear Instagram from iPhone?

Tags: ios, storage, accounts, instagram

I'm having an issue where I'm not able to promote posts on the Instagram app. I was told by Facebook support to delete the app but when I reinstall Instagram after deleting it, all my data and account info is restored.

It's repopulating the same accounts that I had signed in from that device earlier, so I assumed that it may be some local data. It should ask for a fresh sign-in.

How do I completely delete the Instagram app and all documents & data associated with it from my iPhone?

Comment: Basically deleting the app *does* delete its locally stored data. Isn't data you see just the data Instagram gets from the Instragram servers again?

Comment: @nohillside It's repopulating the same accounts that I had signed in from that device so I assumed maybe some local data. They are telling me there is some local data on the app preventing this from working.

Comment: I thought it was iCloud data.. but now i think it can be that all Facebook inc.’s apps share some common storage, like google’s.(you can sign into one app and others just need an ok signal instead of password) so IF, and only IF you don’t care about the WhatsApp chat, try deleting all FB’s apps, and their iCloud data (not chat backups) if any and then reinstalling Instagram. CC @nohill

Comment: Great thought but it's still repopulating my account after delete/reinstall even after deleting WhatsApp, Facebook and Instagram. I tried creating a promotion too from Instagram but it's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

Try this process for deleting the app:

1. Go to **Settings > General > iPhone Storage**
2. Wait for your apps to start populating the list
3. Swipe up to find the listing for Instagram (from memory it's around 100MB in size, but that will depend on how much data you have stored)
4. Tap on Instagram
5. Now you'll see how much space is taken up by the App and its Data, as well as an option to Offload App or to Delete App
6. Tap on Delete App to delete it and all of it's data.

**Note:** Deleting the data itself cannot be undone without doing a full restore from a backup!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Instagram settings and try to find

> [image: "Saved Login Info"]

[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiZrYfG3sXlAhVlITQIHbkrAD8QjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tech-recipes.com%2Frx%2F65414%2Fhow-to-easily-login-to-instagram%2F&psig=AOvVaw2hRDyaGWt9C6q8wEVkqd4X&ust=1572585203936586)

under Privacy & Security (it may have changed in new updates but it should still be there). Then you should be able to toggle it off and remove local username and password information. After deleting the app itself, your login information will no longer appear.

[How to stop instagram app remembering / auto-filling in username at login screen, when not yet logged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131198/how-to-stop-instagram-app-remembering-auto-filling-in-username-at-login-screen)